# In TensorFlow why does tf.train.shuffle_batch hang on forever and won't return batches?

Tags: tensorflow

I am new to tensorflow and am currently trying to produce batches from my data which is in csv format.

I followed the Reading Data Tutorial from Tensor Flow (https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/reading_data) but I must have misunderstood something since my code hangs on forever. 
I used the read_my_file_format function as in the tutorial and it worked. Now I want to train my network for real using batch as follows:

```
def input_pipeline(filenames, batch_size, num_epochs=None):
    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(
         filenames, num_epochs=num_epochs, shuffle=True)
example, label = read_my_file_format(filename_queue)
print('read_my_file is done')
min_after_dequeue = 10
capacity = min_after_dequeue + 3 * batch_size
example_batch, label_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
  [example, label], batch_size=batch_size, capacity=capacity,
  min_after_dequeue=min_after_dequeue)
print('all done but the return')
return example_batch, label_batch

with tf.Session() as sess:
batch_size=5
# Start populating the filename queue.
coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

batch_data,batch_label=sess.run(input_pipeline(file_name,batch_size=batch_size))
print('return is done')
print(batch_data,batch_label)
coord.request_stop()
coord.join(threads)
```

For the sake of debugging, in the code above, I am just trying to print the batch generated not to feed it into a network. With my prints, I was able to see where it hangs : just before the
    return example_batch, label_batch.

My neural network is ready, my data has been processed so this is the only thing holding me from moving forward in my project (Supernovae Classification). Would you have any suggestions or advice ? I've been stuck on this for some times.

Also, if needed, i just have one input file in my filenames.

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't hang in `read_my_file_format` function and you pass correct `file_names` to `input_pipeline`?

Comment: Yes, I checked this and it goes out of the read_my_file_format :/

Answer (score 1):

you need to initialize the variables.

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    ...
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    ...
```

Comment: I will try this thank you ! Actually, yesterday I changed

    with tf.Session() as sess:
    batch_size=5
   # Start populating the filename queue.
   coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    batch_data,batch_label=input_pipeline(file_name,batch_size=batch_size)

   threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
   batch_data=sess.run(batch_data)

   batch_labell=sess.run(batch_label)

And it worked ! Would you have any idea why ?

Comment: Now I've tried to add the num_epochs. And as many people I get the "FailedPreconditionError'>, Attempting to use uninitialized value input_producer_2/limit_epochs/epochs". I've read that this issue is solved by initializing all variable which I do as followed:
"init_op = tf.group(tf.global_variables_initializer(),
                   tf.local_variables_initializer())
sess.run(init_op)"

But I still get the same mistake, any idea why ? Sorry for all these questions..

Comment: Make sure you are running the initialization op after defining the ops that causing the problem. From the error msgs it seems you are not running the initialization op at a proper place.

Comment: Thank you, I changed the place of the initialization and when it is between the coord and the threads it works. Many thanks for your help and patience :)